# How do I pass data context to a custom action filter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I created a custom action filter to perform logging for auditing trails.I added my logging code to `public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)`.

My question is, how do I pass my EF dbContext to this method? I'd like to write a single action filter and re-use it on other development projects without changing the dbcontext for every project.

If this isn't a recommended practice, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were doing such a thing, I think I would be implementing a generic audit logging method in the service layer that already is aware of the data context and pass on an audit model to it. This way, if there's ever a need to log different parts of the application (that may not even be related to controllers), you don't have to re-implement anything.

Alternatively if you want to stick to just controllers you could perhaps make an interface for the data context

```
public interface IDataContext<T> where T : DbContext
{
    T DataContext { get; }
}
```

Create a BaseController that implements in along with `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`

```
public class BaseController : Controller, IDataContext<YourDbContextClass>
{
    public YourDbContextClass DataContext { get { return new YourDbContextClass(); } }
}
```

You can use this base class on controllers and reach the context via `DataContext`, but for logging, you can create a new class with your overridden method

```
public class AuditController : BaseController
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // whatever you do inside here
        // DataContext.LaDiDa
    }
}
```

And then inherit your stuff from it

```
public class HomeController : AuditController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Although this isn't the most straight forward solution, you could lose the interface all together and do everything in the `BaseController`, but I'm just throwing stuff on the board in case you see something that would work for you.